# E4X in ActionScript help needed

Tags: xml, actionscript

Here is the XML

How using E4X read values of nodes

```
<status>௵௸</status>
```

and of node 
    `<invisible value="false"/>` ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" creationComplete="init()">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

            var xml:XML = 
                <iq type="result" id="ss-1">
                  <query status-min-ver="1" status-max="512" status-list-contents-max="5" status-list-max="3" xmlns="google:shared-status">
                    <status>
                      ௵௸
                    </status>
                    <show>
                      default
                    </show>
                    <status-list show="default">
                      <status>
                        ௵௸
                      </status>
                      <status>
                        ௸
                      </status>
                      <status>
                        ௸இ
                      </status>
                    </status-list>
                    <status-list show="dnd">
                      <status>
                        ௵௸
                      </status>
                      <status>
                        dnd, i have bad mood
                      </status>
                      <status>
                        showering
                      </status>
                      <status>
                        ▂▃▄▅▆▇█
                      </status>
                      <status>
                        ௸
                      </status>
                    </status-list>
                    <invisible value="false"/>
                  </query>
                </iq>

            public function init() {
                trace(xml.query.invisible.@value);
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
</s:Application>
```

Comment: I think there is something wrong with your xml code - the nodevalues are strange characters.

Comment: It just unicode text, you think it can be a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `<iq>` is your root node. Reading the value of the first `status` node is as simple as:

```
trace(yourXML.query.status);
```

Reading the value of a property is done like this:

```
trace(yourXML.query.invisible.@value);
```

Edit: I missed that your xml is using namespaces. The `xmlns` here is what defines the namespace:

```
<query status-min-ver="1" 
       status-max="512" 
       status-list-contents-max="5" 
       status-list-max="3" 
       xmlns="google:shared-status">
```

That means you will have to use some extra code to define what namespace you want to retrieve from:

```
import Namespace;
var ns:Namespace = new Namespace("google:shared-status");
```

Then, prefix all your nodes with the namespace:

```
trace("foo:" + xml.ns::query.ns::invisible.@value);
```

Comment: trace(yourXML.query.status) is null
trace(yourXML.query.invisible.@value) is exception :), if answer was so simple...

Comment: without any code it's very hard to be more specific, can you post the code you use to read the xml?